# I changed my e-mail, but Stack Overflow e-mail notices still go to old

Tags: support, user-accounts, email-notification

I have recently changed my email address on Stack Overflow.

It changed as expected, but after the change I'm still receiving Stack Overflow e-mail at my old address rather than the new one.

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're talking about emails for inbox notifications, you need to edit them by clicking the "preferences" button at the top your profile page:

[image: email preferences]

If you're talking about emails for filter subscriptions, you need to go to the filter on StackExchange.com and modify your associated email address there.

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the lack of freehand circles and nice scaling, I'm a bit hurried.